# In React, how can I pass data to a child in runtime rather than on instantiation

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data to a button so that it can validate the data before the app continues. But using props does not work because when I pass in the data, it sends it in upon instantiation, before it ever gets changed by the user. So how can I send the data to the button after the user has given the inputs?

Where the button is being made

```
< SubmitButton title="Create Job" rncfg={runConfigID} targimID={trgtImgID} background_im={bckgrImgID} />
```

runConfigID and the other ID variables are showing their correct values until I pass them into the button, then they show undefined. I honestly do not even know if I am passing them in correctly

Comment: use one of the life cycle hooks to send the data you want. Also, some codes would be good to see what exactly you are doing? and what part is the problem

Comment: new props get passed every time react renders aka state gets updated

Comment: I added code to the question

Comment: Can you post the code where `SubmitButton` is used.